# What are the correct commands in rpm.spec to set-up the systemd preset

Tags: rpm, systemd, rpm-spec

I have a few units in my program, such as:

- program.service
- program-cleanup.service
- program-cleanup.timer
- ...

As well as a 'program-cleanup.preset' file which just says:

```
enable program-cleanup.timer
```

I am having trouble understanding how I should be setting up the files here. Currently my rpm.spec runs the following commands:

```
...
install -D -m 0644 %{_sourcedir}/build/program.service %{_unitdir}/program.service
install -D -m 0644 %{_sourcedir}/build/program-cleanup.service %{_unitdir}/program-cleanup.service
install -D -m 0644 %{_sourcedir}/build/program-cleanup.timer %{_unitdir}/program-cleanup.timer
install -D -m 0644 %{_sourcedir}/build/program-cleanup.preset %{_presetdir}/program-cleanup.preset
```

Do I need to run a `systemctl preset program-cleanup.preset` in the `%post` part of the .spec file? If I add more presets, would I have to add one more line per preset?

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't used **preset** files before, but they look interesting. What seems to be a good setup here (I mention only the relevant parts):

```
%install
install -D -m 0644 %{_sourcedir}/build/program-cleanup.preset %{_presetdir}/program-cleanup.preset

%post
systemd preset program-cleanup.preset

%preun
if [ $1 -eq 0 ] ; then
  # really uninstalling, not upgrading:
  # probably you might want to stop and disable your units when uninstalling:
  systemctl stop program.service
  systemctl disable program.service
  ...
fi

%files
%{_presetdir}/program-cleanup.preset
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be some issues with preset not successfully enabling the units that I've tried to enable inside - not sure if there is some extra step needed other than just copying them and doing the daemon-reload.

Comment: not if I look at the documentation. Make sure the preset files are deployed to a correct location that is detected by systemd...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at `lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.systemd` in CentOS 7 to see that there are lots of nice predefined ones (and that is where `%{_presetdir}` gets defined). It gives you macros like `systemd_post` (which calls `systemd preset`) so you can just have in your `%post` section:

`%systemd_post program.service program-cleanup.service`

Also the [Fedora Packaging Guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd) has an entire section devoted to SystemD.

ETA:

Here's an actual example from some of my code; it's for a mount, but a service *should* work the same. (But maybe not; I may have rebooted, I just don't know.)

This assumes "`%global _buildshell /bin/bash`" being set. In `%install`:

```
# Look for systemd mounts
shopt -s nullglob
for mountf in %{_builddir}/%{?buildsubdir}/unix/*.mount; do
  mfs=${mountf##*/}
  mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_unitdir}/ %{buildroot}/%{_presetdir}/
  cp -v ${mountf} %{buildroot}/%{_unitdir}/
  echo "%{_unitdir}/%{mfs}" >> filelist
  echo "enable ${mfs}" >> %{buildroot}/%{_presetdir}/80-${mfs%%.*}.preset
  echo "%{_presetdir}/80-${mfs%%.*}.preset" >> filelist
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

You'll note this adds the two new files to "filelist" that I then use in `%files` later. That's the only reference to "preset" that I have in that specfile, so I believe the default macros I noted in the original answer "do the right thing" once the `.preset` file is present.

IIRC, enabling services by default that do anything with the network (like listening on ports) is prohibited in the Fedora Packaging Guidelines, so if you ever plan to submit the RPM to them, the preset will likely be denied.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately despite the various docs, I haven't seen any clear answer on whether presets need to be activated or enabled themselves or any such thing. Currently I've got my preset file which enables a timer unit, but even after using ```systemctl daemon-reload``` in ```%post```, as well as rebooting the PC, the timer is not listed at all under ```systemctl list-timers --all```. 

Even manually executing the preset via ```systemctl preset {unit name}``` has no effect, although I can manually enable the timer via ```systemctl enable {unit name}.timer```

Comment: (I will add response to answer, since formatting in comments is hard.)